# Log Output from php file during cron job

Tags: php, ubuntu, cron

I am running a cron job on my local server running Ubuntu 13.10 and want to create a log of the jobs performed.  I can access the main log file, syslog,  that shows if the cron job ran or had errors.

Here is my cronjob (runs every minute while I am testing, script is finished in under a few seconds)

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /home/[usr]/web/X/app/application.php &>> /home/[usr]/Maildir/geocode.log 2>&1 # JOB_ID_2
```

Inside my application.php file, I have several echos that output variables and results of queries performed:

```
echo "STARTING CRON @ ".date("m-d-Y H:i:s")."\r\n";
echo count($properties) . " properties from query"."\r\n";
```

If I run this file from the command line, the file executes correctly and the output is displayed.  After looking up other questions about cron logs, I thought I needed to output the log file by the second half of the cron job:

```
 >> /home/[usr]/Maildir/geocode.log 2>&1
```

Is this incorrect?  How can I save and log the output from my php file?  My file selects a number of object from a database and performs actions on them.  I want to output the number initially worked on, number successfully completed, and any errors.  Right now nothing is outputted, but I know the cron is running because the database it connects to is being updated correctly.

EDIT:
I researched some more and thought 2>&1 would pass stderr into stdout because i wanted all of that info, but looks like this was preventing anything from being written.  Using:

```
/usr/bin/php -f /home/[usr]/web/X/app/application.php >> /home/[usr]/Maildir/geocode.log
```

Adds all of the output I was expecting into the log file, but I am unsure what will happen with errors because it is running fine now.  I will leave this open in case anyone else wants to add anything about creating a log file and if 2>&1 should ever be used in a situation where we want to keep both stderr and stdout.

Comment: just write in your php file to append the data you want to log to .txt file?

Comment: yes, I thought of that but saw another question where that's what the person was doing, but the answer said not to do that because the cron job takes care of the outputs.  I want to understand the cron job better and have been reading more, but will probably just do that.

Comment: I've deployed the `command >> logfile 2>&1` successfully in a variety of systems. I assure you it _is_ the usual way of doing things. Are you editing a crontab file directly, or are you using some library / interface / whatever to edit it? Or if you do it directly, what shell does your crontab use?

Comment: I am using Gnome Schedule 2.1.1.  At first I did edit the cron file directly using the command crontab -e in a terminal window but thought I might have not included a new line at the end and heard good things about this program.  After using it, I looked at it form the terminal and it looked the same as what I was doing.

Comment: I've had problems with 2>&1 at different times and resorted to having > /file and 2> /file split out.